# Conditional statement in an json encoded array

Tags: php, callback, json, conditional-statements

I'm showing a "Review Your Order:" part of a page with the success callback of a json_encode array.  I probably said that completely wrong in technical terms but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do.

Part of the PHP processing page...

```
 $results = array(
 'roomname' => $_POST['roomX'],
 'qty' => $_POST['qtyX'],
```

and I want the results to be returned as...

Room Name:  Whatever is returned.   (notice the label "Room Name: ")

But I only want the label to show IF the POST has a value assigned.

Example of how I think it should look but it's not working..

```
 $results = array(
 'roomname' => if (!$_POST['roomX']=='' { echo 'Room Name: ' .$_POST['roomX'];},
```

Does that make sense?  There are dozens of options for each order and I don't want "Label: " in front of a bunch of values that are empty.

**EDIT:  Added code from answer below.**

```
// beginning of array
$results = array(
'roomname' => $_POST['roomX'],
'qty' => $_POST['qtyX'],
// more code...
// end of array.. remember not to have a comma on this last one.
);

// pasted answer between the array ending and the json_encode line.
if ($_POST['roomX'] != ''){
$results['roomname'] = "Room Name: ".$_POST['roomX'];
}

$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one way, you can user a [Ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

```
$results = array(
 'roomname' => $_POST['roomX']==''? 'Room Name: '.$_POST['roomX']: '',
 );
```

this will add a blank string if the value is empty

the other way will be to just add the value later;

```
$results = array(...);

if ($_POST['roomX'] != ''){
$results['roomname'] = $_POST['roomX']
}
```

Comment: Is this suppose to be at the end?  }  I don't see another one.

Comment: @LITguy sorry this was a typo

Comment: when you say "add the value later"..  on the same PHP processing page where the array is?  Or where I'm catching the success callback?  the first bit of code isn't sending anything now.

Comment: what i mean is if the value is optional it will only be added (in the same page)  if it meets the condition, otherwise your array will not have the `'roomname'` index

Comment: Perfect!  Very much appreciated explanation.  I love actually understanding it rather than copy+paste.  Thank you!  I combined yours with the Room Name: label.  I'll paste it in an EDIT above in my post.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an if statement before assigning any data to roomname like so

```
$result = array( 
    'roomname' => ($_POST['roomX'] !== '')? 'Room name: '.$_POST['roomX']:''
);
```

The thing I used here is a shortend if statement and works as following: (if statement)? true : false;

I hope this will help you.

Comment: "Shortend if statement" isn't really a thing; that's the ternary operator or conditional operator. It's not really the same thing as an `if` statement.

Comment: ok that makes sense but is there an extra ) at the end or do I need to add one somewhere else?  I'm counting 5 parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();
if (isset($_POST['roomX'])) {
   $results[] = array(...);
}
```

if there's no post value, you just end up with an empty array.

Comment: exactly but if there IS a post value, I need that label affixed and just wondering how to add it.  I think red Ibu has it.  just testing it out.  thank you!